# How to coding divisible number in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a problem about divisible number because I want to use the number of ticks to code in my project. For example, I want the turtle to start doing something in specific time (like in every 30,60,90..., number that able to be divided by 30).

I have no idea about it so if you guys have any suggestion about it?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the modulos operator. In your forever go function, you could use the following code that checks whether enough ticks have passed.

```
if ticks mod number = 0 [ask turtles [do-something]]
```

Don't forget to tick your simulation at the end of your go.

Comment: I have some more question here. If I want the turtle to do something on routine like go to work and back to home like this, how could I code it? It seems like if I use this code, maybe it does not work.

Comment: I don't see how this code wouldn't work. You just need to define the function. Implement the function "go-to-work-or-home" then call it: if ticks mod number = 0 [ask turtles [go-to-work-or-home]]

Comment: If you have another question, please open a new question, instead of adding comments to an existing one. That's how we do things here on Stack Overflow: one question at a time.